# Kubernetes Horizontal Pod Autoscaler with Prometheus Metrics (prometheus-adapter)

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-adapter

I have this use case:

> When there is much load on a specific queue in RabbitMQ, i want to start more replicas. Let's say, my app can handle 5 messages ( = tasks) simultaneously and they all take 1 min to complete. When there are more than 10 "ready" messages in the rabbitmq Queue, i want the HPA to start a new replica. When there are 20 "ready" messages, start 2, at 30 "ready" messages start 3 etc.

I used this helm chart for install prometheus-adapter:

https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/prometheus-adapter

And in my helm values yaml i added:

```yaml
rules:
  default: true

  custom:
    - seriesQuery: '{__name__=~"rabbitmq_detailed_queue_messages_ready"}'
      name:
        matches: "^(.*)"
        as: "open_tasks"
      resources:
        overrides:
          kubernetes_namespace: { resource: "namespace" }
          kubernetes_name: { resource: "service" }
      metricsQuery: sum(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>,queue="my-task-queue"}) by (<<.GroupBy>>)
```

Now, this should be exposed, but it isn't:

```bash
$ kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 | jq . | grep open_tasks
```

Now this is my main question. After that i could deploy an HPA for my app `task-processor` like this:

```yaml
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
metadata:
  name: task-processor-autoscaler
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: task-processor
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
    - type: Object
      object:
        metric:
          name: open_tasks
        describedObject:
          apiVersion: "/v1"
          kind: Service
          name: open_tasks
        target:
          type: Value
          value: 10
```

Now my questions:

1. Why is the metric not exposed in the raw query?
2. Is my yaml for the HPA correct? I have the feeling that i'm missing some essential stuff here, but i'm not able to get my head around that.

Comment: Why `describeObject`? It should reference the object that the metric is associated with. And isn't `open_tasks` a metric, not a Service?

Comment: You are right, could you make an example how you mean it? I couldn’t get my head around it.

Comment: @Stefan did you managed to make it work ? having this same issue

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is essentially autoscaling based on RabbitMQ queue length, which is a bit challenging due to the limitations of the native Kubernetes HPA controller, as it "typically" autoscale based on CPU and memory usage.

**Alternatively, you may consider utilizing [KEDA](https://keda.sh/docs/2.10/concepts)** (Kubernetes Event-Driven Autoscaling):

KEDA is a Kubernetes-based event-driven autoscaler. With KEDA, you can drive the scaling of any deployment based on the various criteria (depends on the scaler adapter). It supports [RabbitMQ](https://keda.sh/docs/2.10/scalers/rabbitmq-queue), which makes it particularly suitable for your case.

Here's a sample `ScaledObject` for your case:

```
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1 # Optional (default: apps/v1)
    kind: Deployment
    name: task-processor
  triggers:
  - type: rabbitmq
    metadata:
      queueName: 'my-task-queue'
      mode: QueueLength # Trigger on number of messages in the queue.
      value: '5'  # Target number of tasks per pod.
```

Answer (score -1):

It might be that **Kubernetes does not understand custom metrics out of the box,** making it not exposed.
 
You can check [Santhosh Nagaraj](https://www.linkedin.com/in/santhosh-nagaraj-s/) article [Scaling Celery workers with RabbitMQ on Kubernetes](https://learnk8s.io/scaling-celery-rabbitmq-kubernetes) that can provide you insights about your use case using KEDA.

Comment: It does support it through Prometheus-Adapter. The blog post you linked is a few years old when it was not supported.